# Do I need to enable authentication for MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've just set up MongoDB, got a hold of `mongoose` as well and while I was following some tutorial of connecting to the database I have noticed that there's no user/password being required by default which lead me to the following question:

Is that a security issue when moving to production? What security measures do I need to take? Would anyone be able to access MongoDB remotely? How to suppress that if so.

Comment: check this - https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/add-admin-user/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is problematic if access is possible from the internet (i.e., is not firewalled, has a weak/no password, or not bound to localhost only). Attackers might be easily able to access your DB and read all data. This is not just a theoretical threat, see http://www.cso.com.au/article/566040/students-find-40k-unprotected-mongodb-databases-8-million-telco-customer-records-exposed/ for a recent "indicent".

The mongodb developers provide a [security checklist](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/administration/security-checklist/) and also provide a [security tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/).

So, at least set a [password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872495/3906760) and at best [bind it to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4961177/3906760) only (also problematic if other users also have access to that machine) in order to prevent brute force attacks.

Comment: The binding to localhost part ( having nobdy else to access my machine ) seems like the most reasonable answer. I'll also go for auth credentials ! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, You have stumbled upon a valid question.

You check out this source:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html

And have a code which does something of this sort:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('integration_tests', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017,
 {auto_reconnect: false, poolSize: 4}), {w:0, native_parser: false});

// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  // Add a user to the database
  db.addUser('user', 'name', function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    // Authenticate
    db.authenticate('user', 'name', function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(true, result);

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Just adding a few more sources you might want to have a look at:

1. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/administration/security-checklist/
2. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/

Hope this is a good starting point in your quest for productionizing MongoDB!

Answer (score 3):

Security should be a multi-layered approach.

- First of all, in production, I would recommend putting MongoDB on a separate physical machine.
- I would restrict access to this machine via the firewall, such that only MongoDB traffic on port `27017` can access the MongoDB machine from the webservers.
- I would only allow `ssh` access to the MongoDB machine or the webservers from specific IP addresses which need access to them.
- I would use only key-based authentication for SSH to both the Webservers and MongoDB machine.
- I would completely block the MongoDB machine from accessing the internet, aside from NTP for time synchronization.
- Although I feel the above steps are more important, I would enable MongoDB authentication.

  - This is a weak layer of security, though, since only the webservers should be able to access port `27017` on the MongoDB machine, and anyone who compromised the webserver would be able to extract the MongoDB password from the source code on the server.
  - If you have multiple MongoDB databases, you can use different authentication credentials for each database, to add a level of isolation between applications.

In short, no, you don't need authentication, but it can add an extra layer of security. The other layers are far more important.